# How do you use two different user IDs for the same Android application?

Tags: android, uid

There has been lot of discussion how to use the same user ID for two applications.

I have a little bit strange situation where I want to provide two user IDs for one application. For example, from the same application, activity 1 and 2 will use a different user ID, or a service will run on a different user ID then rest of the application.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I hate when people answer a question with - why would you want to do that? - but I am curious. There's an interesting article here http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html I read once about editing values in the installation file. Maybe you could set a value here. If all you need is different process Ids you could just start an activity with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

Comment: to get it clear, you want 2 users to be able to use the same app. after passing an authentication screen and depending on the user Id the app. will behave differently??

Answer (score 0):

This is generally not possible unless you want to split your application into two packages (`.apk` files).

See [the documentation here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#userid).